# Is there any way to determine data type to value of json dynamic object in json.net?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a `json` string that I deserialize it to `dynamic json` object. But number values convert to `dynamic{long}`!!! How can I determine data type of number?

My code:

```
_jsonStr = "{unSelectedTest_1:{TestId:109},unSelectedTest_2:{TestId:163}}";
dynamic a = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(_jsonStr);
foreach (dynamic v in a)
{       
    dr["TestId"] = v.Value.TestId.Value;
}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "determine"? What are you trying to achieve that you can't achieve now? I suspect Json.NET is just using `double` for anything with a decimal point (or possibly values too big for `long`), and `long` for anything else.

Comment: Why long? why not int for little number type? My mean's is there any way I say json.net convert numbers to int instead of long?

Comment: If that's what you want your question to be asking, I suggest you edit it to make that clear.

Comment: I can't see anything in `JsonSerializerSettings` for this. It would be easy to write your own method to convert a `long` to an `int` if it's in range though.

Comment: OK, but why value is dynamic{long}  and is not long? It mean all of child values of dynamic variable are dynamic too?

Comment: As far as the compile-time type is concerned, yes. But the value itself *is* just a long.

Comment: So the answer to that *immediate* question is just to call `GetType()` on it... but that still doesn't sound like the question about making it deserialize as an `int` instead of a `long`.